# Prob. 13 (a), Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: For $c>0$, $f(x) = x^a\sin\left(|x|^{-c}\right)$ is continuous iff $a>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

Here is Prob. 13, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $a$ and $c$ are real numbers, $c > 0$, and $f$ is defined on $[-1, 1]$ by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^a \sin \left( |x|^{-c}\right) & \ \mbox{ (if $x \neq 0$)}, \\ 0 & \ \mbox{ if $x = 0$}. \end{cases} $$ Prove the following statements:
>
> (a) $f$ is continuous if and only if $a > 0$.
>
> (b) $f^\prime(0)$ exists if and only if $a > 1$.
>
> (c) $f^\prime$ is bounded if and only if $a \geq 1+c$.
>
> (d) $f^\prime$ is continuous if and only if $a > 1+c$.
>
> (e) $f^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exists if and only if $a > 2+c$.
>
> (f) $f^{\prime\prime}$ is bounded if and only if $a \geq 2+2c$.
>
> (g) $f^{\prime\prime}$ is continuous if and only if $a 2+2c$.

My Attempt:

> Here we can assume properties such as the continuity and differentiability of the sine function.
>
> (a) We note that $f$ is continuous at all $x \in [-1, 1]$ such that $x \neq 0$. Now suppose that $a > 0$. Then we see that 
>   $$ \left| f(x) - f(0) \right| \leq |x|^a. $$
>   So for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, if we choose $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta \leq \sqrt[a]{\varepsilon}$, then $$\left| f(x) - f(0) \right| < \varepsilon$$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$ for which $|x-0|<\delta$. Hence $f$ is continuous (even at $0$).
>
> Next suppose that $a \leq 0$, and let 
>   $$x_n = \left( 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{-\frac{1}{c}} \ \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}. $$ 
>   Then as $c > 0$, so 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0,$$ but 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align} 
> \lim_{n \to \infty} f\left( x_n \right) 
> &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{-\frac{a}{c}} \sin \left( 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \\
> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{-\frac{a}{c}}  \\
> &= \begin{cases} +\infty \ \mbox{ if $a < 0$} \\ 1 \ \mbox{ if $a=0$}.\end{cases}
> \end{align} $$
>   In any case, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f\left( x_n \right) \neq f(0)$$, showing that $f$ is not continuous at $x = 0$ if $a \leq 0$.
>
> Hence $f$ is continuous if and only if $a > 0$.

Is this proof correct and rigorous enough for Rudin?

Comment: The idea is right. I think there are errors in your calculation of $f(x_n)$. Additionally, until you have determined whether or not $f(x_n)$ converges, you should not write $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$.

Comment: @arjafi can you please allow me to keep my original title? I find it more desirable to have it that way.

Comment: @Jason can you please have a more careful look through my post and see if there are actually any errors?

Comment: There is an error - go through your calculation and find it! Plus, as I said, you have written $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ before you know this limit exists.