# For $c>0$, $f(x) = x^a\sin\left(|x|^{-c}\right)$ is differentiable at $0$ iff $a>1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Here is Prob. 13(b), Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $a$ and $c$ are real numbers, $c > 0$, and $f$ is defined on $[-1, 1]$ by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^a \sin \left( |x|^{-c}\right) & \ \mbox{ (if $x \neq 0$)}, \\ 0 & \ \mbox{ if $x = 0$}. \end{cases} $$ Prove the following statements:
>
> (b) $f^\prime(0)$ exists if and only if $a > 1$.

---

### My Attempt:

First of all we assume the usual properties such as the continuity and differentiability of the sine function.

Since continuity of $f$ is necessary for differentiability, therefore we can assume that $a > 0$. Here is the link to an earlier post of mine where I have tried to prove this. [For $c>0$, $f(x) = x^a\sin\left(|x|^{-c}\right)$ is continuous iff $a>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269938/prob-13-a-chap-5-in-baby-rudin-for-c0-fx-xa-sin-leftx-c-ri)

Our $f$ is differentiable at every point of $[-1,1]$ except possibly at $x=0$.

Suppose that $a > 1$. Then 
$$f^\prime(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h^{a-1} \sin \left( |h|^{-c} \right) = 0 ,$$
for, given any real number $\varepsilon > 0$, if we choose a real number $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta \leq \left( \varepsilon \right)^{\frac{1}{a-1}}$. Then for any point $h \in [-1, 1]$ such that $0 < |h| < \delta$, we see that 
$$\left| h^{a-1} \sin\left(|h|^{-c}\right) - 0 \right| \leq |h|^{a-1} < \delta^{a-1} \leq \left( \left( \varepsilon \right)^{\frac{1}{a-1}}  \right)^{a-1} = \varepsilon. $$

Now we suppose that $0 < a < 1$. Then $1-a > 0$, and so 
$$f^\prime(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{\sin \left( |h|^{-c} \right)}{h^{1-a}},$$
and the last limit fails to exist.

Am I right?

Comment: Should that be $|x|^a$ in the definition of $f?$

Comment: @zhw. Rudin has not used the absolute value.

Comment: looks like Rudin made an error then

Comment: In the last bit you have the right idea, but it would be better to not write down $f'(0)$ there. After all, you're trying to show $f'(0)$ does not exists.