# Prob. 13 (c), Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: For $c>0$, $f(x) = x^a\sin\left(|x|^{-c}\right)$ has a bounded derivative iff $a>1 +c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

Here is Prob. 13, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $a$ and $c$ are real numbers, $c > 0$, and $f$ is defined on $[-1, 1]$ by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^a \sin \left( |x|^{-c}\right) & \ \mbox{ (if $x \neq 0$)}, \\ 0 & \ \mbox{ if $x = 0$}. \end{cases} $$ Prove the following statements:
>
> (a) $f$ is continuous if and only if $a > 0$.
>
> (b) $f^\prime(0)$ exists if and only if $a > 1$.
>
> (c) $f^\prime$ is bounded if and only if $a \geq 1+c$.
>
> (d) $f^\prime$ is continuous if and only if $a > 1+c$.
>
> (e) $f^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exists if and only if $a > 2+c$.
>
> (f) $f^{\prime\prime}$ is bounded if and only if $a \geq 2+2c$.
>
> (g) $f^{\prime\prime}$ is continuous if and only if $a > 2+2c$.

My Attempt:

> We assume the usual properties such as the continuity and differentiability of the sine function.
>
> Now $f^\prime$ exists (at all points $x \in [-1, 1]$) if and only if $a > 1$. The proof of this I have tried to supply in my previous post at the following link. [For $c>0$, $f(x) = x^a\sin\left(|x|^{-c}\right)$ is differentiable at $0$ iff $a>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269997/prob-13-b-chap-5-in-baby-rudin-for-c0-fx-xa-sin-leftx-c-ri)
>
> First, suppose that $a > 1 + c$. Then we find that 
>   $$ f^\prime(x) = \begin{cases} a x^{a-1} \sin \left( |x|^{-c} \right) - c \  \mathrm{sgn}(x) \ x^{a-c-1} \cos \left( |x|^{-c} \right) & \ \mbox{ if $x \neq 0$}, \\ 0 & \ \mbox{ if $x=0$}. \end{cases} $$ 
>   Now $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, as $c > 0$, and as $a > c+1$, so we have $a-1 > 0$, $a-c-1 > 0$, and therefore 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \left| f^\prime(x) \right| 
> &\leq |a| \cdot |x|^{a-1} \cdot \left| \sin \left( |x|^{-c} \right) \right| + c |x|^{a-c-1} \cdot \left| \cos \left( |x|^{-c} \right) \right| \\
> &\leq |a| + c \\
> &< +\infty,
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   which implies that $f^\prime$ is bounded.

Am I right?

> Now we suppose that $1 < a \leq 1+c$. Then $0 < a-1 \leq c$, and so 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align} 
> \lim_{x \to 0} \left| f^\prime(x) \right| 
> &= \lim_{x \to 0} \left| a x^{a-1} \sin \left( |x|^{-c} \right) - c \  \mathrm{sgn}(x) \ x^{a-c-1} \cos \left( |x|^{-c} \right)  \right| \\
> &\geq \lim_{x \to 0} \left(  \left| c \  \mathrm{sgn}(x) \ x^{a-c-1} \cos \left( |x|^{-c} \right) \right| - \left| a x^{a-1} \sin \left( |x|^{-c} \right)  \right| \right) \\ 
> &= c \lim_{x \to 0} \left( |x|^{a-c-1} \left| \cos \left( |x|^{-c} \right) \right| \right) - |a| \lim_{x \to 0} \left( |x|^{a-1} \left| \sin \left( |x|^{-c} \right) \right| \right) \\
> &= 
> \end{align} 
> $$

Is what I have done so far correct?

If so, then am I headed in the right direction? If so, then how to show from this point on that $f^\prime$  is unbounded?

Comment: what about $x^a $ if $x <0$

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima we can of course bring in complex numbers here, can't we?